# understanding the steps for cloning and pushing on Github

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am using GitBash version 1.9 on Windows and wondering if anyone can confirm whether the following steps I am gonna follow are correct or not?

```
1) $git clone https:...............

After making changes, that is replacing the old file with new file. I need to go to the correct directory using cd directoryname and then following the following steps: 

2) $git add .

3) $git commit -m "Added Updated File"

4) $git  pull

5) $git push -u origin master
```

Please confirm as I don't want to mess up with my repositories and this is my first time I am cloning and pushing on to GitHub

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

number 4 is not necessary . Just push after committing. Others are OK.

Comment: no, but it is considered good practice so you don't have to get a message saying "rejected"

Comment: @sircapsalot When I run Step 5, I get the following message `"sh.exe": push: command not found` just below `$ push -u origin/master`  Anyone has any idea how do I rectify this error?

Comment: @John you forgot the `git` bit.  `git push --set-upstream origin master`  (you of course you can use the shorthand of `-u` instead of `--set-upstream`)